# Bash Script If else statement not capturing the threshold

Tags: linux, bash

I am currently attempting to capture the threshold in my script, but it's reading as everything is "above the threshold".

I know that the directory is at 48G and I set the threshold to 99G, expecting "Not above threshold" to appear after running the script. Please advise and see script below for reference...

```
#!/bin/bash

threshold=99

if [ "du -sh /data | cut -f1 | grep -Eo [0-9]+ -gt $threshold" ]
then
    echo "Reducing file with a further commands. File is above the threshold..."
else
    echo "Not above threshold..."
fi
```

Comment: Commands aren't executed inside double quotes. You want `$(du ...)`

Comment: Note that `[` isn't generic shell syntax -- it's the name of a command also called `test`. If something wouldn't be a valid argument to `test`, you can't pass it as an argument to `[` either.

Answer (score 3):

You want:

```
if [ "$(du -sh /data | cut -f1 | grep -Eo '[0-9]+')" -gt "$threshold" ]
```

Double quotes create a literal string, you need to use `$(command)` to substitute the output of a command into the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Using `--threshold` option

```
value=99
THRESHOLD=$(du -sh --threshold="${value}"G /data)

if [ -n "$THRESHOLD" ]
then
    echo "Reducing file with a further commands. File is above the threshold..."
else
    echo "Not above threshold..."
fi
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the feedback. This helps.